# mvc3 - implementing a variable type recursive model with editors..

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, recursion

I'm quite new to MVC3, just learning and am looking for some guidance.

For sake of simplicity, I have a model that represents 3 types of elements, questions, answers and containers.

All 3 inherit from a common base type, which I'll call baseElement.

When the model is delivered to the view it is a single object of type 'baseElement'

The container elements have an internal list of baseElements. 
Those baseElements can be of any of the three types. So - containers can contain questions, or containers (which could also contain questions, containers, etc..)

Each question can contain different types of answer types.

I'm trying to figure out how to use mvc3 to best implement a system to display this container/question structure to the user - permitting them to answer questions with various answer types while respecting the nested structure of the incoming model.

Comment: How is this nesting supposed to work on interface level? Is there a limit to the nest? What happens when you have containers 16 levels deep? How is the view expected to respond?

Comment: This is generally a problem.  MVC has some issues parsing complex objects.  It can be done, but it's usually much less painful to rethink your model and view strategy.

Comment: I used backbone.js to handle a similar situation instead of mvc views.

Comment: @Joel Etherton At the interface, you can think of containers as divs that contain each of the nested elements. Divs can contain other divs or questions, etc. It maps pretty well conceptually to a UI and I've built a UI successfully with webForms. There is no limit to the depth, although in common usage the depth doesn't get past a few levels.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, despite the dynamic nature of my model, after poking around for awhile longer I've been able to render my model object structure without too much complication.

I did it by using a strongly typed Editor Templates (one for each type), and the following code in the View.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => @Model, @Model.GetType().Name)
```

This automatically chooses the proper editor template to use based on the actual type.
In each of the type specific Editor Templates I make the same call for each of the children.

It actually ends up being pretty simple.

The big problem I'm running into now, is how to model bind (or otherwise retrieve) the form values back into something usable once it's posted by the user. The dynamic nature of the structure causes the default model binder to cross it's arms and give up.

At this point I think retrieving/remapping the form data might be a much bigger issue, but that will certainly require more tinkering, and perhaps a separate question.

Thanks for the help.
:-)